# Add custom header to UITableView using Storyboard

Tags: iphone, uitableview, header

I can't seem to be able to add a header to a UITableView using a Storyboard. I have a UITableView with a few prototype cells which are showing up and working fine. I then dragged a new UIView above these prototype cells and added a label to it to act as the header of my table (NOT as a section header). I created a new subclass of UIView with one single property which is the UILabel. The class of the UIView in the storyboard is set to this custom UIView, and the referencing outlet of the UILabel is set to the UILabel property of my custom UIView class.

Then, in my UITableViewController's viewDidLoad method, I'm doing the following:

```
DetailTableHeaderView *headerView = [[DetailTableHeaderView alloc] init];
headerView.entryNameLabel.text = @"TEST";
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

But when I run my app the table header is not showing up at all. I also noticed that the text property of the headerView.entryNameLabel is not even set to the "TEST" as it should be.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How does the storyboard know what to load for the tableview header? You're just initializing the view controller, but there's no view to go along with it!

Comment: Don't know what you mean exactly. In the storyboard, I added an UIView with an UILabel inside it as the table header. I then created a custom UIView subclass called 'DetailTableHeaderView" which contains an UILabel property named 'entryNameLabel'. In the storyboard, I've set the class of the header view to be 'DetailTableHeaderView', and I've linked the UILabel referencing outlet to the UILabel 'entryNameLabel'.  Isn't that sufficient?

Comment: How does the storyboard know how what view to load? You haven't told it to perform any segues, and judging by your comment, I'd wager that the `view` in question does not have any link to anything, it just appears in the storyboard. Try: `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailTableHeaderView"];` to set up your `UITableViewHeader`. Make sure that `DetailTableHeaderView` is a `UIViewController` though.

Comment: But the header view can't be a view controller. There's a UITableViewController already and you can't add a second view controller to the same window.

The storyboard knows what to load because I've dragged a new UIView above the prototype cells and I've set the class property of this new UIView to be of the UIView subclass which I programmatically created. That is how it's usually done and it works for everything else. For some reason this doesn't work for the table header though...

Comment: You use the view controllers `view` property when settings the header view. Just keep a reference to the view controller, and you're good to go. Prototype cells are different, as they are a property of `UITableView`, and not the storyboard.

Comment: Hmm but the UITableView has a view property called 'headerView' which can be used to customize the header view. In all tutorials that I've found it's being done like this. When I programmatically create a new UIView with an UILabel in it and add this to the UITableView's headerView it works. It just doesn't work when I layout the new view in the storyboard. Where exactly should I keep a reference to the view controller? And to which view controller exactly?

Comment: Define a pointer in the header file, allocate the view controller in the `viewDidLoad` method, then set the `headerView` property to the view controllers `view` property.

Comment: Okay will try that today, except that I only have a view to allocate, not a view controller.

Comment: But I don't have a view controller, I have only a view! In my storyboard I have a window with a UITableViewController. I can't add a second view controller to that! I'm dragging a UIView above the UITableView in the storyboard. This is how it is explained in the Apple documentation...

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I am providing my answer for reference reasons since it's still a bit non trivial how to add a tableview header, using storyboard for the design part.

1. Add a prototype cell in your tableview in your storyboard.
2. Having your prototype cell selected, in the attributes inspector on your right, give it an identifier (ex headerViewCell), since this is how your will reference it in order to use it.
3. Now click on the size inspector tab and give it a row height (this gonna be your header view height)
4. In the code now, in the controller that handles the tableview:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"headerViewCell"];
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

This question is very old but writing this answer in hope that this will help someone.

The good way to handle table headerView is by using delegate methods. Implement `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection` and `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection`delegate methods. Return your UIView from `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection`method.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
}
```

Another option is to use a prototype cell (custom cell) for header view and return it in tableView:viewForHeaderInSection method. See below code (I have not tested this one):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{

    HeaderView *headerView = [self.TableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"tableHeader"];

    // Set Text
    headerView.headerLabel.text = @"Some title";

    return headerView.contentView;
}
```

**UPDATE**

The above also works for tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: method. Here is sample code:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UITableViewCell *sectionHeader;
    CustomSectionHeaderCell *sectionHeaderCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"sectionHeaderCell"];

    // do stuff here

    return sectionHeaderCell.contentView;
}
```

Comment: You are not answering the question. This is not what he wants.

Comment: Lots of confusion here between table header views and table **section** header views. A table view can have only one table header view, which is always at the top of the table view. A table view can have multiple section header views, which are displayed on top of the section they are associated with.